# Как избежать повторения одинаковых фрагментов кода в программе

Tags: python

В программе приходится часто писать следующую конструкцию:

```py
time.sleep(0.5)
txt="Как?"
for i in txt:
    time.sleep(0.03)
    print(i, end ="",flush=True)
```

Хочу сделать как-нибудь легче, чтобы не приходилось постоянно писать один и тот же фрагмент кода.
Только начал изучать программирование, не разбираюсь.

Comment: Облеките в функцию.

Comment: Здравствуйте, а это как?

Comment: @kolck Ну почитайте где-нибудь про функции. В питоне функция оформляется через ключевое слово `def`.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией.
Пример:

```
def my_func(text):  # объявляем функцию с именем my_func и аргументом text
    for i in text: 
        time.sleep(0.03)
        print(i, end ="",flush=True)
```

Вызов функции:

```
my_func(txt)  # тут txt - аргумент (ваша переменная), внутри функции будет использоваться под именем text.
```

Когда выполнение функции завершится - переменная text перестанет сущетсвовать (она является локальной для функции)

Совет по дальнейшему изучению функций - изучите аннотацию типов и необязательные параметры.

Comment: Название функции не по `PEP`, **camel case** - для классов, а функции должны быть в нижнем регистре, для функции-примера используют например название `func`.  Ну и `i_txt` не очень хорошее название, в чём смысл привязывать название параметра функции к переменной цикла `i`? Я бы просто `text` назвал.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, подправил.

Comment: Аннотации типов — лишний груз для новичков. Пусть лучше классы изучают. Необязательные параметры тоже необязательны.

Comment: @Глеб , возможно. Хотя грамотное использование классов довольно сложная тема и начинать лучше с функциональщины. Моя рекомендация призвана показать, что функции бывают «функциональнее» того, что приведено в примере)

Comment: Вы правы, конечно, начинать нужно с функций. Просто аннотации и трюки с аргументами — это уже самые сложные темы. В функциях есть много другого, что стоит изучить.